# How can I get the mean of sequence of frames using Opencv & Java?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I want to get the mean of the sequence of frames in order to get the background image. I've seen a lot of examples that use Python or C++ but I can't implement those examples in Java.

I can't use accumulate method of Opencv because I can't divide the mat using a constant value so I tried using accumulateWeighted method but it produces a background model with blended objects in the scene. I want to obtain a perfect background model using Opencv and Java.

I hope someone helps. Thank you!

P.S. 
I'm using Opencv 2.4.10

Comment: did you try to use [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/video/BackgroundSubtractor.html). it creates a background image which you can obtain by [getBackgroundImage method](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/video/BackgroundSubtractor.html#getBackgroundImage(org.opencv.core.Mat))

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet. Thanks for suggesting! :)

Comment: see also [the corresponding tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :) Will definitely read and study that. :)